# OnClick function in Android not starting any activity

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

The button are appearing over the main screen, but on clicking on them, nothing is happening.

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
 {

    Button brsignin;
    //ImageView image1;
    Button Voicerecog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        brsignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.brsigin);
        //image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        Voicerecog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Voicerecog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.brsigin:

                Intent i = new Intent(this,signin.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.Voicerecog:

                Intent j = new Intent(this, VoiceRecognitionActivity.class);
                startActivity(j);
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the line: `yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You must add setOnClickListener to make system recognizes that your class is using On Click Listener class

```
brsignin.setOnClickListener(this);
Voicerecog.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: then you choose best answer ;)